# Junit with maven program is not working

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

When i run this i am getting Initialization error and there is no console error.
I have attached my junit test code and pom.xml code. please help me with the solution. And its a Maven project.

Junit program:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class JunitTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // fail("Not yet implemented");
        System.out.println("Junit code");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
        Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchDropdownBox")));
        s.selectByVisibleText("Books");
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("harry potter");
    }

}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.testmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you have this property System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/vishnu/Desktop/cet/chrome/chromedriver.exe");

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace, it will help us to debug this issue

Comment: Where is the unit test located in your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a build phase in POM for doing the compilation of integrated unit tests.

add this code snippet in *pom.xml* for running the test classes.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

You can find more information on:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html